# Annotated form validation - conversion failed custom message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm analyzing spring-mvc-showcase example project ([spring-mvc-showcase github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase)). Confused with the way validation response is presented on JSP page when I hit incorrect date format (Birth Date field on screenshot). How can I make it more user friendly with some custom message, without those ConversionFailedException details?

screenshot:

[image]

Annotation-driven validation is applied. Down below is code segment from bean class representing birthDate field.

FormBean.java

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
@Past
private Date birthDate;
```

Method responsible for form submit:

FormController.java

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@Valid FormBean formBean, BindingResult result, 
                            @ModelAttribute("ajaxRequest") boolean ajaxRequest, 
                            Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return null;
    }
    // Typically you would save to a db and clear the "form" attribute from the session 
    // via SessionStatus.setCompleted(). For the demo we leave it in the session.
    String message = "Form submitted successfully.  Bound " + formBean;
    // Success response handling
    if (ajaxRequest) {
        // prepare model for rendering success message in this request
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return null;
    } else {
        // store a success message for rendering on the next request after redirect
        // redirect back to the form to render the success message along with newly bound values
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
        return "redirect:/form";            
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your view.

Comment: This is public github example, I pasted link at the beginning of my post. Here is exact view form.jsp:

[link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/form.jsp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note, that you are working with *binding errors* here. These are thrown long before the actual JSR-303 validation is performed and they override JSR-303 constraint violations for the failed field.

Codes for the binding errors are `typeMismatch`. So you can add for example this to your messages properties:

```
typeMismatch.birthDate = Invalid birth date format.
```

Check JavaDoc for [DefaultMessageCodesResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html) and [DefaultBindingErrorProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultBindingErrorProcessor.html) to discover how Spring's error code resolution works.

Comment: In my servlet-context.xml I put this:
`<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>`

In messages.properties added this row, as you recommended:
`typeMismatch.birthDate`

Nothing happens

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Just cloned the project myself, added message source + the message and it works. Where is your `messages.properties` file located?

Comment: You're right. Unintentionally I put it in src/main/webapp folder. Now I moved it in src/main/resources and it works like a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: Links are broken

Answer (score -1):

Did you used error tag ? 
you can use message property in your validation annotation.
like here :

@NotEmpty(message = "serverIP can not be empty")
    private String serverIP;

Comment: This error isn't coming from a validation annotation, but from the Spring DataBinder, so no change to the validation annotations is going to affect its message.