# How to add custom error message in org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm doing a form validation using **Bean Validation API** with my custom messages:

```
@NotNull(message = "Please enter your birthday.")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
@Past(message = "That's impossible.")
private Date birthday;
```

Everything works good until I put wrong date format. Then I got such a long and verbose error message on my page:

```
Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
[java.util.Date] for property birthday; nested exception is
bla-bla-bla...
```

As there is no field `message` in `@interface DateTimeFormat` from `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat` I cannot add my message there as I did with other annotations.

How can I specify custom message like `"Please use MM/dd/yyyy format"` there?

Comment: Note that what you see is a conversion, not a validation error. Validation kicks in only after the bean has been initialized with values converted from String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use MessageSource bean and messages.properties file and there you can add key-value like below.

```
typeMismatch=Please use MM/dd/yyyy format
```

If you are using SpringBoot then MessageSource bean will be available by default and you only need to add key-value in messages.properties. For normal Spring application you can use ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource or ResourceBundleMessageSource.

Property key is resolved in following order.

```
typeMismatch.[form].[property] 
typeMismatch.[form]
typeMismatch
```

Please refer http://jtuts.com/2014/11/09/validating-dates-in-spring-form-objects/

Comment: I already have this bean and file, I skipped this in the question to simplify it. Btw `message.properties` is using only for convenience by externalizing messages to a separate file. Ok and where to point this `typeMismatch` property within entity class?

Comment: You don't need to point this key. Annotation @DateTimeFormat will automatically pick up the key-value from message.properties file. I have updated my answer. Please see.

Comment: You're welcome. And don't forget to accept the answer if it resolves your issue. This will be helpful for others.

Comment: How does DateTimeFormat picks up the message? I don't see this code anywhere in the annotation source code.
I have defined the `typeMismatch=something` in my `messages.properties` file and that error is not picked up automatically. I have to manually wire the MessageSource bean in my ControllerAdvice and call `.getMessage(code, null, Locale);`

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to add custom error message is through [DefaultMessageCodeResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html)
You can use the resolver to bind errors at object + field level(typeMismatch.YourClassName.birthday = custom message.) as mentioned in the javadoc.

Find a detailed usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19092536/6159397)